# Where can I get C code for TCL scripting language?

Tags: tcl

I am new to TCL and trying to dig the  `C` code that runs TCL commands , I installed TCL in windows . Not able to find the `C` code .

Can anyone suggest me where can I get the `C` code ? or any links ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For browsing, see [here on core.tcl.tk](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/dir?ci=tip) which is a web view into the code repository. The directories you're most likely to want to look inside are [*generic*](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/dir?ci=tip&name=generic) (platform-independent code, most of Tcl) and [*win*](http://core.tcl.tk/tcl/dir?ci=tip&name=win) (Windows-platform code, build instructions). The other main directories there are *unix* (Unix-specific sources), *mac* (Mac-specific build system), *library* (Tcl library files; no C code) and *doc* (documentation in a format that you've probably never encountered before).

For code relating to a specific version of Tcl, see [the Tcl file distribution area on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl/files/Tcl/). Pick your version, download the exact sources you want. Note that they'll be laid out in virtually the same way as in the repository: look in *generic* and *win* to see the C code.

Comment: How can I know which is the first (main) file ?

Comment: @user3103694: On Windows, that's win/tclAppInit.c, but that delegates most of the work to generic/tclMain.c (the function is called `Tcl_MainEx`). Assuming you're talking about _tclsh_, of course. When embedding Tcl, you don't use the main loop stuff (since that'd be in your own code).

Answer (score 1):

You are new to Tcl and yet, you go for the C source code already? What is your goal? Are you trying to learn Tcl, or learn C? Any way, the source can be found here:

http://tcl.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am seeing TCL code in library folder . Where can i see C files ?